# Problems in storing multilingual website data into database

Tags: database, web, event-handling, character, multilingual

I am making a multilingual website and storing data into database. The problem I am facing is, some of the character in some languages other then English are not being inserted into data base. For example if I enter "cliënten" [Dutch language] into form text area or input box, when I submit this. it only insert "cli" but nothing after this character ë the problem is clear. it seems a special charterer. 
 Now can anybody tell  me how to insert characters like this into database from all other languages?

Thanks in advance to all you experts out there.

:-)

Comment: Probably helps to specify which operating system, database and programming language you are using... some actual code examples would also be useful.

Comment: Yes. It's obviously an encoding problem, but it's hard to give a solution when there's no info about the environment.

Comment: Sorry for not giving the complete info guys, i am using windows 7 , mysql database and php for programming. here is and example, when i insert this pera in the text area "<p>Trachten we onze cliënten zo goed en zo volledig mogelijk van dienst te </p>"    then it will just insert this portion in the database <p>Trachten we onze cli"  now you can see that charecer ë in word "cliënten " is causing this problem, but big problem is many charecter of this kind may exist in many languages so how to insert them in to database?

Answer (score 0):

You could start by checking the character set and the collation of the database. If you are using phpMyAdmin, open the database and you will probably see a column titled 'collation' for each of the tables. Ideally I think you will want utf8.

More info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-database.html

If the database looks good, then if you are loading details via a web page, check that you have specified the charset there as well with something like this in the page head:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```